Is the name "Negation" accurate?
I am self learner newbie.
As I read Definition of Negation,
I read the definition here in Wikipedia and also ChatGPT told me:

The definition of negation in logic essentially centers on contradiction: negation of a proposition , written as ¬, is a statement that is true whenever  is false, and false whenever .
Formally: For any proposition , ¬ is defined as "not ". This means that ¬ holds precisely when  fails — or, in other words, the truth value of ¬ is the opposite of . In logic, negation acts as the mechanism that establishes dichotomy or binary opposition within a system by declaring that for any statement, there is an opposite or negated version, thus structuring truth in two opposing ways.

I don't feel Negation is saying False is opposite of True, it's simply defining a Relation between the two States, True and False. By opposite I mean, "opposite" somehow gives a sense of conflict, where there isn't any. They are merely two Independent States related via Negation. Am I correctly understanding it?! A name like "Otheration" or "Dualation" would be more apt, in the sense that they don't give the impression of "opposite".
Thanks,
Ashish

Can you explicitly quote the definition of negation you came across? That would make this question clearer. If False and True are defined in your text, it might be good to add their definitions too.

Maybe, but it is impossible to legislate about language. Language changes by its own.

What do you think "opposite" means? Please make this question more clear by editing it.

Negation is not 'saying' False is the opposite of True because negation is not the opposite. The opposite of white is black but its negation is non-white, a much broader property. Red, green and blue are all non-white but none of them is black. The "opposite" does not even always make sense (what is the "opposite" of gray?), but negation always does.

@DavidGudeman Good Question, never really thought of defining opposite, it's more like "opposite" somehow gives a sense of conflict, where there isn't at all. They are merely two Independent States related via Negation. Will update question as well. Thanks.

@Conifold Correct but while non-shite is a bigger set, here in Classical Logic, there isn't a bigger set, there is just one "other" not "opposite" but "other" possible value.

@mrnobody "not positive" could also be "zero". "not dogs" could also be "nothing". Only with the additional rule of "there is not nothing" (in logic the rule of the excluded middle) those equalities are appropriate

"opposition" doesn't necessarily mean conflict: https://www.etymonline.com/word/opposition So if things are orthogonal they might also be in opposition to each other without being in conflict with each other. Although that always depends on how you end up using these words.

The term 'negation' can mean different things, even within logic. There is a surprisingly large literature on the subject, e.g. this article in SEP. Entire books have been written about negation, such as Lawrence Horn's A Natural History of Negation, Chicago, 1989.
Negation and falsehood are fundamentally different concepts. 'True' and 'false' are semantic concepts: they are truth values that a proposition may have. Negation is usually handled within logic as a syntactic concept: it may be thought of as an operation on a proposition that yields another proposition. In classical logic there is a simple relationship between falsehood and negation: if a proposition is true then its negation is false and if a proposition is false then its negation is true.
But this does not hold in other logics. There are many logics where the bivalence of true/false does not apply. Furthermore, the underlying notion of negation that classical logic assumes is not the only one.
The most common way that negation is treated in logic is as a relation of complementation. Not-white is the complement of white. Not-Canadian is the complement of Canadian, etc. Not true is false, provided we assume that true and false are the only possibilities and so are complementary. This is perhaps what you are referring to when you speak of "Otheration" or "Dualation".
But there are alternative ways of understanding negation. We can think of negation as subtraction. We might think of P as the assertion that P is the case, and not-P as its denial. On this basis, "P; not-P" is not a contradiction as such but rather the assertion of P followed by its retraction. Or we may think of negation as a privation, or as a relation of incompatibility.
In English we can negate sentences, verbs and predicates.

It is not the case that this box has been damaged.
This box hasn't been damaged.
This box is undamaged.

It is a simplification, probably due to Frege, to treat negation in classical logic as applying only to propositions. It keeps the logic simple, but it involves some loss of expressibility.

EXACTLY!!! "complementation" is the word I was looking for. Thanks! Yes it's complementation not Negation.
I do know there are Multi Valued Logic were nonsense or absurd etc. as also the truth values but keeping it to Classical Logic, Negation is Actually Complementation. See why I worry about it so much, I plan to be teaching kids this some day, and the thought process that a kid will build about Logic will depend upon how He/She sees these Fundamental Concepts. This is what they ACTUALLY are, COMPLEMENTS OF EACH OTHER in Classical Logic...

Part of the reason the term negation is used is historical. Negation literally means 'denial'. According to etymonline.com:

early 15c., negacioun, "an act of denial," from Old French negacion (12c.) and directly from Latin negationem (nominative negatio) "denial," noun of action from past-participle stem of negare "deny, say no," from PIE root *ne- "not." As "a negative assertion," mid-15c.

So, the terms truth, falsity, and negation are interrelated because people will tell truths, will lie, and will deny. These terms are psychologically interrelated.  You seem to think that truth-as-logical-primitive is disconnected from truth-as-experience. But ultimately, various theories of truth are not just formal systems used to precise truth-conditional semantics, but rather are integral to human thought and natural language. So between tradition and the psychological appeal of using intuitive concepts, it doesn't make much practical sense to rename 'negation' 'otheration' or some other artificial and unappealing term.

Just musing, what if the term was appealing and cool!
Thanks for the answer though. I undesrtand the connection with Natural Language but within formal system people do invent or redefine terms to suit the purpose...

Here is the truth table for the negation operator:

In the context of a formal proof, the statement "P" can, for convenience, be thought of as meaning "P is true." The statement "not P" can be thought of as meaning "P is false."

I think the confusion lies in this statement:

Negation is saying False is opposite of True

With this wording it sounds like "negation" is the concept that "false" is the opposite of "true". That concept is called "bivalence".
Negation is a operand that basically says "something else but not this". If we look at the alphabet and say "NOT X" (the negation of X) then it means "any letter that is not the letter X". So "A" is "NOT X" and so is "B". Even no letter at all would be "NOT X". Only "X" would not be "NOT X".
Or to be precise the "set" {{A}, {B}, {C} ... {W}, {Y}, {Z}, {}} = NOT {X}
However in a bivalent system, only true and false exist (even "nothing" does not exist). So when you say "NOT true" only one value exist that satisfies this claim which is "false". And vice versa: "NOT true = false" and also "NOT false = true".
The better way to phrase your statement would rather be:

Bivalence is saying "false" is the Negation of "true"

(which is ofcourse not a full definition of bivalence)

The term 'negation' is used here in the sense of "negate : (1) to nullify". The negation operator nullifies the following term, which in formal logic means that it flips the truth value: true becomes false; false becomes true.
Thinking of negations as 'opposites' makes sense in formal logic, because formal logic is binary and binary states oppose each other. But in the real world we rarely have simple binaries. For instance, when we use the word 'tall' there is no simple meaning to 'not tall'. We usually have one of the following:

A relational spectrum: e.g. Sally is tall (compared to the rest of us, but not compared to, say, giraffes)
A normative value: e.g. everyone 6' or more is defined as 'tall'
An identifier: e.g. we call him 'Tall Joe' even though he's not the tallest person around

Saying something is 'not tall' in the real world nullifies the adjective 'tall' nonspecifically: e.g., is (1) shorter than Sally, (2) shorter than 6', or (3) some Joe other than Tall Joe. That doesn't align well with the simplicities of logic.
